# Can't read Ubuntu partition on Windows 8

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, unallocated

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 with a Live CD, and it seemed to work. However, when I boot into Windows 8, it shows up as Unallocated space. When I use Gparted, it shows up properly. I wanted to use a dual-boot system using the Windows 8 boot manager instead of GRUB. I have EasyBCD and that can't read the partition either. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 is not capable of reading the ext4 filesystem, which is Ubuntu's default file system.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different tools in both Linux and Windows for examining the disk, and they react in different ways -- even within one OS. Thus, it's not clear precisely what the problem is you're seeing in Windows. It's possible that you're encountering [this problem,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-fs-code/index.html) but I can't be positive of that. If so, see the page to which I linked for a full description and a fix. (You just need to change the type code on your Linux partition(s).) If it's something else, please provide a clearer description, including the program(s) that are showing unexpected results, and perhaps a screen shot.

If you're booting in EFI mode (as is likely if the computer shipped with Windows 8), EasyBCD will be useless for managing multi-booting -- or at least, that was the case the last I heard. GRUB can handle boot management duties, or you can use another boot manager, such as [gummiboot](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/gummiboot) or my own [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)